# Clone Windows 10 to Multiple PC

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, clone

As Windows 7 support end soon, I am planning to have all PCs to have clean install of Windows 10. But installing them one by one on every PC is very time consuming and I am thinking to take this opportunity to have clean refresh for all PC.

So, I am thinking to have clean install of Windows 10 with some commonly use application on one PC (license not activated). Then, clone that drive to all the other PC (Every PC has different kind of hardware & setup). Only then, I will install proper driver for each PC and put in license to activate the software.

Is it possible and OK to do that? Will there be any side effect (such as cloned version will run much slowly or random error) with this method?

Comment: You need a Windows 10 Volume license and use Sysprep to do this. I am often into small numbers so we use Windows 10 OEM and set them up. It goes fairly fast

Comment: From https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/move-full-operating-system-pc/          
There are no guarantees that your cloned copy will work successfully on a new machine. Often, the drivers for your new and old hardware won’t match. In the best case, certain parts of your new machine won’t function. In the worst case, your computer won’t boot, and you’ll see a “blue screen of death.”

Of course, you could use the installation disc or even the problematic device’s website to find the new drivers and fix the problems, but it can be a time consuming and frustrating process.

Comment: We are always glad to help, but a question of this nature would probably be more appropriate within the [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) community.

Comment: you can use Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (MDT) : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54259 ( instructions are in the related resource section)

Comment: Mass deploying Windows is a very well documented process. I strongly suggest that you read the links suggested here so far.